# Minimising MSE of $\sigma^2$ estimator of specific form

Tags: self-study, variance, maximum-likelihood, expected-value, estimators

I have found a past exam question for a statistics course and can't seem to find the required result.

[image: The Question]

Part A is fine but my working for part B must be incorrect [see below]. Can anyone figure out where I've gone wrong? I suspect it may have to do with the range of possible theta values, or that I'm using E[] wrong. Or, perhaps I have to take an MLE approach using the log likelihood function instead?

**Update** My working between lines 2 and 3 is less clear as it incorporates multiple steps, so to explain:
I take the sigma^2 outside of the sum as I believe it is a constant
Sigma^2 is theta according to the question, hence the appearance of the theta

[image: My working]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In going from line 4 to 5 you took an expectation inside a squared term, going from $E[(\text{something})^2]$ to $(E[\text{something}])^2$.

You should probably fix that and carry it down.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, thank you.
However what is the best way to take the expectation of the square of the sum of a standard normal variable?

Comment: @Chris The difference between the two things I wrote is a variance ($\text{Var}(\text{something})$). Part (a) wasn't there just for fun. You're expected to use it in (b) ... that's actually how I spotted your error, I realized you hadn't used the result in (a) and so had a good idea where to start looking for the problem..

Comment: Took me a little while to work out how to deal with that but I have posted the final results below. Thank you so much @Glen_b

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to Glen_b for helping spot my error, here's the final working I've come up with which does indeed find the required result:
[image: Corrected solution]